# Debugging Perl programs in KDevelop

Tags: perl, debugging, kdevelop

I can create new Perl projects in KDevelop, and KDevelop provides automatic syntax highlighting of my `.pl` files. However, I don't see a way to debug my Perl programs (e.g. add breakpoints, debug step-by-step, etc.).

Is this possible with KDevelop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According [to this table in perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Perl%20Development%20Tools), Perl debugging is not supported by KDevelop. You can use Eclipse with EPIC to debug Perl scripts.

Comment: Another usable graphical debugger for people who don't want to use Eclipse is [GNU DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/).